# SQLProvider : how to join with options / nullable columns

Tags: sqlite, f#, type-providers

I have been trying to replicate this with [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) :

```
SELECT c.ticker, hc.ticker 
FROM currencies c
LEFT JOIN currencies hc on hc.id = (CASE WHEN c.offshore_hedging_currency_id IS NULL THEN c.id ELSE c.offshore_hedging_currency_id END)
```

I have tried the following and variations, but I can't seem to get results.

```
let q = 
  query {
    for c in db.Main.Currencies do  
    let tmp = if c.OffshoreHedgingCurrencyId.IsSome then c.OffshoreHedgingCurrencyId.Value else c.Id
    join hc in db.Main.Currencies on (tmp = hc.Id) 
    select (c.Ticker, hc.Ticker)
  }
```

offshore_hedging_currency_id is nullable.

I also tried a simpler :

```
SELECT c.ticker, hc.ticker 
FROM currencies c
LEFT JOIN currencies hc on hc.id = c.offshore_hedging_currency_id
```

But the following won't work as nullables are converted to options (hence the compiler complains)

```
let q = 
  query {
    for ccy in db.Main.Currencies do  
    leftOuterJoin ohc in db.Main.Currencies on (ccy.OffshoreHedgingCurrencyId = ohc.Id) into result
    for ohc in result do
    select (ccy.Ticker, ohc.Ticker)
  }
```

Thanks a lot